# How to write jQuery inside of C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, z-index, scriptmanager

I need a Javascript or jquery inside my codebehind in c#
I works like it should if i place it inside the div. But now I want the script inside an if else

Look at the part where the id is chart2

```
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:0; ">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div  ID="chart2"style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1">
       <script>$("#chart2").css("z-index",0);</script>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1;">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1;">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart4" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div> 
</div>
```

But if i write it inside the if-else it does not affect anything.

```
                  else if (n == 2 && chart.Width == "50%")
                    {

                        literal = ltrRenderChart2;   
                        string script = "<script>$(\"#chart2\").css(\"z-index\",0);</script>";
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(ltrRenderChart2, ltrRenderChart2.GetType(), "Script", script,false);
                    }
                    else if (n == 2 && chart.Height == "50%")
                    {
                       literal = ltrRenderChart2;

                         string str = "<script>$(\"#chart2\").css(\"z-index\",0);</script>";
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(ltrRenderChart2, ltrRenderChart2.GetType(), "Script", str, false);
                    }
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is jQuery loaded in your page?

Comment: what is `chart` here ?

Comment: Be careful with that `<script>` tag! I remember, that Visual Studio has some major issues with it in ascx and aspx files, because it parses it as a server sided script tag! I remember times, where we had to split it like that: `"<scr" + "ipt>"`. I couldn't believe this behavior until I first encountered it ...

Comment: @Markus The <script> tags don't need to be there at all.

Answer (score 1):

If u write inside C# like this:

```
string script = "<script>$(\"#chart2\").css(\"z-index\",0);</script>";
```

then C# will consider it as a string value.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "script ", script , true);
```

And by using the ScriptManager, you add your javascript script to the page like shown above

Comment: I just found that you're not allowed to write the <script> tags, but it is still not working